# How is 'in the middle of the night' different from 'midnight'?

Tags: difference, word-difference

Is 'in the middle of the night' different from 'midnight' in the sense that:

the former refers to unspecific late time in the night,

and the latter refers to definite time; midnight = 12am?

Am I right? Are there any other differences?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

We tend to use "**the middle of the night**" to refer to, just as you guessed, a general time (or time period) during the part of the night where most people are probably asleep.

Another phrase you might hear is "**in the dead of night**," with "dead" referring to the stillness and quietness at that time.

Midnight is then, simply, 12am.

Comment: One more thing please; when we say that 'midnight is 12am' and 'midday is 12pm', does it mean exactly 12.00? Is 12.15, 12.20, 12.35 not considered midnight or midday?

Comment: I call 12:00 pm "noon" or "midday".

Comment: @LaithLeo You can, of course, refer to any time vaguely. "Midnight" might not be exactly 12:00:00am. But I wouldn't expect to hear someone refer to "midnight" if they meant 1am or similar. Phrases like "some time around midnight" give you more leeway.

Comment: I'm not sure of your explanation for **dead of night**.   I think it could be related to how "dead" is used in **dead center**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'm not convinced by an adverb origin either, though. The dictionary seems to define "dead" as a separate noun, though doesn't seem to reveal its specific origin. It's from as far back as at least the 1500s as a phrase, and seems literary in origin. As a result, perhaps we can only surmise what the author was implying.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  I expect "dead" here is related more to *activity* than *position*, as in "Being a night guard is pretty boring -- it's pretty **dead** around here at 2 AM"